# php in html in .php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

working in wordpress here.

I have this code to trigger a popup for a plugin.

```
<?php PopupContact(); ?>
```

It is supposed to insert a `contact us` button, and trigger a popup when clicked.

In another .php file, I have the following code

```
<p><?php wc_ps_ict_t_e( 'No Result Text', __('Click Here To Request A Quote For A Part That Hasn\'t Made It To Our Site Yet.', 'woops') ); ?></p>
```

What I would like to do is replace `"Click here"` with the `Contact Us` button

However I cannot insert the `<?php PopupContact(); ?>` successfully.

when I attempt

```
<p><?php wc_ps_ict_t_e( 'No Result Text', __('<?php PopupContact(); ?> To Request A Quote For A Part That Hasn\'t Made It To Our Site Yet.', 'woops') ); ?></p>
```

The browser only returns `"To Request A Quote For A Part That Hasn't Made It To Our Site Yet"`

If you could provide any information on why this is happening, and anything I could do to fix it I would really appreciate it.

If you need any more information from me, please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: What function is "wc_ps_ict_t_e"?

Comment: PopupContact(); returns beside the contact us button the script needed for it to be working

Comment: wc_ps_ict_t_e is a function from another plugin, that provides an error message when the users' search query returns no results.

Comment: What exact string does `PopupContact()` generate?

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I read the code, PopupContact() does an echo in and of itself.  If you want to put the contents of that echo into something else, you'll need to use output buffering.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  PopupContact();
  $popup = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
?>
<p><?php wc_ps_ict_t_e( 'No Result Text', __($popup.' To Request A Quote For A Part That Hasn\'t Made It To Our Site Yet.', 'woops') ); ?></p>
```

Generally, functions shouldn't echo out like this, but I'm not sure what the rest of your stack looks like.  You should also check out the contents of $popup to make sure that it isn't too complex to go into your output function.